# Finding Max in Matlab

Tags: matlab, max

If there are multiple arrays, such as if there were an array of speed, distance, and time. How would I find the max of speed and the distance and time at which it occurred?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `max` command returns as a second argument the index of the max element.
So, if you have three vecotrs **of the same size** representing `velocity`, `distance` and `time`, you can simply:

```
>> [mxv ii] = max( velocity ); % find max speed and its index
>> [distance(ii), time(ii)] % distance and time corresponding to max velocity
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming,

```
>> distance = [1:5]; % any array
>> time=[11:15];% any array
>> speed=distance./time;
>> [max_speed,index]=max(speed);



% max_speed Occurred at time(index), distance(index)
```